# migrate sonarqube history from one server to another

Tags: sonarqube, openshift

I have deployed one sonarqube server with a postgresql database in an openshift 3 cluster.
The versions that i use are respectively 8.4.2-community and 9.5 for my database.

I am currently in the process of migrating my project in a new openshift 4 cluster.
I have deployed a new sonarqube server with a postgresql db with the exact same versions that i used before. Now is the step where i have to migrate the project history of the old sonar to the new one. i already tried to dump from the old database to the new one , but that did not work so well.

open to solutions for those who want to help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Project Move](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/project-move/) feature of SonarQube Enterprise Edition.

It will allow to export and import of the projects in SonarQube.

> **Note:** Administrative access is needed to perform `Project Move`.

Comment: if i got it right it is only available for those who use the enterprise edition or am i wrong ? i am using community one

Comment: Oh my bad, i missed the version you mentioned in the question. Yeah, `Project Move` is available for EE version.